# Valor inesperado está sendo exibido

Tags: c, tipagem

> 9. Faça um programa que receba o número de horas trabalhadas, o valor do salário mínimo e o número de horas extras trabalhadas, calcule e mostre o salário a receber, seguindo as regras abaixo:
>
> a. A hora trabalhada vale 1/8 do salário mínimo;
>
> b. A hora extra vale ¼ do salário mínimo;
>
> c. O salário bruto equivale ao número de horas trabalhadas multiplicado pelo valor da hora trabalhada;
>
> d. A quantia a receber pelas horas extras equivale ao número de horas extras trabalhadas multiplicado pelo valor da hora extra;
>
> e. O salário a receber equivale ao salário bruto mais a quantia a receber pelas horas extras.

#### Código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Variáveis
    double numero_horas_trabalhadas;
    double salarioMinimo;
    double numero_horas_extras;
    double valor_hora, valor_hora_extra, salarioBruto, salarioTotal;
    //Entrada de dados
    printf("Olá, vamos calcular o seu salário!");
    printf("\nDigite as horas trabalhadas: ");
    scanf("%f",&numero_horas_trabalhadas);
    printf("\nDigite o valor do salario minimo: ");
    scanf("%f",&salarioMinimo);
    printf("\nDigite o numero de horas extras trabalhadas: ");
    scanf("%f",&numero_horas_extras);

    //Processamento
    valor_hora = salarioMinimo/8;
    valor_hora_extra = salarioMinimo/4;
    salarioBruto = (numero_horas_trabalhadas * valor_hora);
    valor_hora_extra = (numero_horas_trabalhadas * valor_hora_extra);
    salarioTotal = salarioBruto + valor_hora_extra;
    //Saída de informação
    
printf ("O valor do salario minimo e : %f",salarioTotal);
```

Comment: O seu primeiro problema postado aqui foi resolvido? Qual é o problema deste agora?

Comment: O primeiro foi resolvido sim.

Comment: O erro deste é no processamento, o salario final está exibindo 0

Comment: Procure sempre postar o máximo de informações possíveis para ajudar as pessoas entenderem seu problema. Depois dá uma olhada nisto: [tour]. Já achei o problema desta.

Comment: Você tentou imprimir os valores individuais lidos? E os valores intermediários? Isso pode te ajudar a identificar melhor onde está o erro em vez de olhar pro programa como um todo e imaginar onde ele pode estar.

Comment: Ok, obrigada! Me desculpe, sou nova por aqui então ainda estou aprendendo. Muito obrigada pela força!

Comment: @KarolayneSantos é normal demorar um pouco para pegar o jeito, estamos aqui para ajudar. Não esquece de ler o **[tour]**

Answer (score 5):

O problema é a *tag* de formatação do `scanf()`. Para ler uma valor do tipo `double` o correto é `%lf` e não apenas `%f`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Variáveis
    double numero_horas_trabalhadas;
    double salarioMinimo;
    double numero_horas_extras;
    double valor_hora, valor_hora_extra, salarioBruto, salarioTotal;
    //Entrada de dados
    printf("Olá, vamos calcular o seu salário!");
    printf("\nDigite as horas trabalhadas: ");
    scanf("%lf",&numero_horas_trabalhadas);
    printf("\nDigite o valor do salario minimo: ");
    scanf("%lf",&salarioMinimo);
    printf("\nDigite o numero de horas extras trabalhadas: ");
    scanf("%lf",&numero_horas_extras);
    //Processamento
    valor_hora = salarioMinimo/8;
    valor_hora_extra = salarioMinimo/4;
    salarioBruto = (numero_horas_trabalhadas * valor_hora);
    valor_hora_extra = (numero_horas_trabalhadas * valor_hora_extra);
    salarioTotal = salarioBruto + valor_hora_extra;
    //Saída de informação
    printf ("O valor do salario minimo e : %f",salarioTotal);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AFZwZW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pfnzfrsv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfFormat.c).

---

Para saber mais sobre as especificações de formatação:

## [Format string specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications)

Comment: Muito obrigada!